# Capybara: is it possible to specify the Scenario name for save_and_open_page

Tags: capybara

I was wondering if it's possible to rename the default file that's created when using save_and_open_page in Capybara for the Scenario name?

I've created the following so far:

```
After do |scenario|
   if(scenario.failed?)
     save_and_open_page 
   end
end
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`save_and_open_page` [can take an optional filename parameter](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Session#save_and_open_page-instance_method):

```
save_and_open_page('page.html')
```

Comment: Thank you, I've now seen that I can use scenario.title to create the name... cheers!

Comment: I'm pretty sure I saw this working one time yesterday, but now I'm trying the same and getting `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)`, `...bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/capybara-1.1.4/lib/capybara/session.rb:290:in `save_and_open_page'`, `...bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/capybara-1.1.4/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:161:in `save_and_open_page'`, `   def save_and_open_page
291      require 'capybara/util/save_and_open_page'
292      Capybara.save_and_open_page(body)`. Any idea what the problem could be? Cheers!

Comment: @mickael Looks like optional parameter appeared in Capybara 2.0. Compare session.rb in Capybara source

Comment: I see... maybe I saw it working in a different project then. And do you know how I could upgrade the version? I've checked in this project with `gem list` and I'm getting `*** LOCAL GEMS *** capybara (2.0.1)`. On my **gemfile** I've just got `gem "capybara"` (without any version), and then if I try to upgrade with `gem upgrade capybara` I get the message `Updating installed gems. Nothing to update`. Do you know what could be causing the problem and how to overcome it? Many thanks for the help Andrey! :)

Comment: ah, now I realized that `gem list` doesn't list the same files as `bundle list`, so it turns out that 'capybara > 2' needed 'xpath > 1' but someone has specified a version below that for xpath in the gemfile. Removing that restriction and doing `bundle update` fixed the problem. Thanks for the tip!!